# How to pass a parameter in p:ajax when we used it with p:inputText?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to pass a parameter in my p:ajax method . there is a `<p:inputText>` and when I finish typing my input Box have to update my p:ajax method. But i am not able to send the parameter in my method.

My jsf page is :

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['elicense.contractorFormRenewal.personal.registrationNo']}"/>
<p:inputText id="registrationNo" value="#{renewalContractorBean.registrationNo}"  required="false" label="Registration No">
    <p:ajaxlistener="#{renewalContractorBean.readLicenseDetailsById(renewalContractorBean.registrationNo)}/>
</p:inputText>
```

and my method in bean is

```
public void readLicenseDetailsById(String id) {
    FirmOrCompany firmOrCompany = contractorRenewableService.readLicenseDetailsById(id);
    this.setLicenseName(firmOrCompany.getLicensePersonName());
    this.setClassofLicense(firmOrCompany.getLicenseAppliedFor());
}
```

Comment: There is no such a thing as `<p:ajaxlistener>`?

Comment: Why are you passing the value in the page, when it exists in the backing bean, along with the method that needs it? why can't you use the instance variable from within `readLicenseDetailsById` without it being passed in?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<p:ajaxListener>`, i don't know if you missed your code or the question.

Considering you made a mistake in the question, your method should work fine, you just forgot to set the `event=blur` in `<p:ajax>`, so it get called once you leave the inputTextBox(means that the user already done typing)

```
  <p:inputText id="registrationNo" value="#{renewalContractorBean.registrationNo}" required="false" label="Registration No">
       <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{renewalContractorBean.readLicenseDetailsById()}/>
  </p:inputText>
```

Check that if you want to update another component, based on the changes you made in your bean, you must specify the id of that component in `<p:ajax>`, `<p:ajax event="blur" update"IdOfTheComponent" ....>`

Also, you don't have to pass properties which is already in your bean as a parameter, you can just get it in your bean.

Finally, in `renewalContractorBean`:

```
public void readLicenseDetailsById()
{
  String id = this.registrationNo;
  FirmOrCompany firmOrCompany= contractorRenewableService.readLicenseDetailsById(id);
  this.setLicenseName(firmOrCompany.getLicensePersonName());
  this.setClassofLicense(firmOrCompany.getLicenseAppliedFor());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you tryupdate="tableid" ? When I delete from a list which in p:dataTable, JSF can update this dataTable I hope this will be helpful.
Here is my code to update my p:datatable

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" value="#{borrowerBean.borrowers}" var="bor">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel>ID: </h:outputLabel>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bor.id}"/>
            </p:column>
.
.
.
    <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{user.deleteBorrower(bor.id)}" update="tbl"/>
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```